# A strange phenomenon of vector member in a class

Tags: c++, vector

All the header file included,

```
class Test{ 
public:
    vector<int> vector_int(10);
    Test(int num);
    ~Test();
};

Test::Test(int num){
    cout << "constructor employed" <<endl;
    vector<int> vector_int;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        vector_int.push_back(i);
    }
    cout<<"The size is " << vector_int.size()<<endl;
}

int main(){
    int num = 10;
    Test* a = new Test(10);
    cout<< a->vector_int.size()<< " is the size"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result: constructor employed
The size is 10

0 is the size

It seems to me that these sizes should be the same. The constructor is also employed. What is the problem then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are shadowing the class member variable `vector_int` with a local variable of the same name in the constructor.

Remove the line `vector<int> vector_int;` from the constructor and it should work as expected.

Comment: I think the right word is "hiding" rather than "overriding".  Or maybe there's a better word still.

Comment: @MooingDuck: "shadowing."  In fact if you use `gcc -Wshadow` it will flag this error.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Agreed, fixed

Comment: THX! Is it because that the vector member is allocated space at declaration?

Comment: @ydxu You completely missed the point. `vector<int> vector_int;` should not be declared in your constructor function. It provides a local instance of `vector_int`, that's unrelated to your class member variable `vector_int`, and actually ***hides it*** .